# cursor.getLong(1) not throwing Exception

Tags: android, database, cursor, android-sqlite

I have an field in database that is null
When I retrieve it in a cursor it is null.
I can tell that from the

> cursor.isNull(1) is true
>   So when I do **cursor.getLong(1)** it should throw an exception according to the documentation. but it actually retrieves 0 without and exception.
>   any ideas why?

Comment: what is the type of that variable stored in the db?

Comment: Long but the default is NULL and currently it has null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the implementation of the method `getLong()` in MatrixCursor , you can see the following code:

```
    @Override
public long getLong(int column) {
    Object value = get(column);
    if (value == null) return 0;
    if (value instanceof Number) return ((Number) value).longValue();
    return Long.parseLong(value.toString());
}
```

If the value is null, then 0 is returned.